# javascript new Function with await doesn't seem to work but with no error message

Tags: javascript

syncTest works, await asyncTest doesn't but there's no error message, so I can't see how to fix this ?

```js
function syncTest(a) {
  return a;
}

async function asyncTest(a) {
  return a;
}

async function test() {
  let value1 = new Function(
    `return syncTest("123");`
  )();
  console.log(value1);

try {
  let value2 = new Function(
    `return await asyncTest("123");`
  )();
  console.log(value2);
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(error.message);
}

}

test();
```

Comment: There is an error message. _"ReferenceError: error is not defined"_. Once that is corrected you then see another error message _"await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"_

Comment: `await` can't be used in a regular function that isn't `async` (which is what `new Function()` is creating), you can create your own `AsyncFunction` variable and use that (as shown on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction))

Comment: @evolutionxbox I used online playground and there's no error.

Comment: Look in the dev tools console

Comment: @user310291 not sure... most likely because of the issues with `e` vs `error` in your code, or maybe because when they run your code it does give errors (which is the opposite behavior to what you were seeing), so they think you haven't debugged enough, but I'm just guessing

Answer (score 1):

2 possible problems:

Using **await** most likely means the function will return a Promise, not plain text. [Learn about it here, you won't regret it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises).

Second, the "new Function" command you are using is quite odd, and most likely isn't asynchronous in this case. The **await** keyword only works in asynchronous functions, E.g. (async()=>{}) is an asynchronous function.

Please take this all with a grain of salt, as I am unable to test this at the moment. Just some words of wisdom! ✨